# javafx swing crashes when trying to display chart twice

Tags: java, swing, javafx, charts

I'm making a java swing application with javafx charts added to the `JFrame`. Click a button it shows a chart in a new window. All works fine the first time around, but on closing the chart window and click a button again, it crashes before displaying the next chart window, at the line

```
fxPanel.setScene(scene);
```

I think `fxPanel` or `scene` need to be reset when closing the chart window the first time, but nothing I've tried has worked so far. Below is my chart plotting class. Any help muchly appreciated.

```
public class PlotChart extends JFrame implements WindowListener {

    private JFrame chartWindow = new JFrame("Commitment Of Traders");

    public PlotChart(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
        plotChart(fxPanel);
    }

    public void plotChart(JFXPanel fxPanel) {

        final NumberAxis xAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        final LineChart<Number,Number> lineChart = new LineChart<Number,Number>(xAxis,yAxis);
        final Scene scene = new Scene(lineChart,800,600);
        xAxis.setLabel("Week");

        lineChart.setTitle("Commitment of Traders");

        //Define a series
        XYChart.Series commercials = new XYChart.Series<>();
        XYChart.Series nonCommercials = new XYChart.Series<>();
        XYChart.Series CLong = new XYChart.Series<>();
        XYChart.Series CShort = new XYChart.Series<>();
        commercials.setName("Dealers");
        nonCommercials.setName("Hedge Funds");

        //Populate series
        for (int i=0;i<ReadCSV.getCommercials().size();i++) {

            commercials.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i,ReadCSV.getCommercials().get(i)));
            nonCommercials.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(i,ReadCSV.getNonCommercials().get(i)));
        }

        lineChart.getData().add(commercials);
        lineChart.getData().add(nonCommercials);

        fxPanel.setScene(scene); // exception in this line

        chartWindow.add(fxPanel);
        chartWindow.setSize(800, 600);
        chartWindow.setVisible(true);
        chartWindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        chartWindow.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {

            public void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent windowEvent) {

                ReadCSV.clearVars();
                System.out.println("window closed");
            }
        });
    }
```

`WindowListener` method overrides omitted

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please quote stack trace or error message in the question (format stack trace as code).

Comment: Hi Ole, thanks for reply, there is no error message it just freezes. I tried surrounding with try/catch but still doesn't give error...

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue as well just now. I managed to get rid of it by creating a new JFXPanel each time and hence setting the scene only once on each instance.
It solves the issue, but probably isn't the most elegant way to solve this.